# Auto Refresh Data In Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I using visual studio 2010 and using Entity Framework, and SQL Server 2008 R2. I have after trigger on my table, and When Save one record in table, another column in other table changed.
Is it possible to change automatically changed record on my application.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you want an already queried entity to get the updated property when the trigger occurs? AFAIK that's not possible without requerying the entity. Triggers happen on the database side.

Comment: Is there a reason why you have to have your "trigger" on the database?

Comment: Triggers add complexity to the solution and in many occasions you will find other solutions that does the job better. Unless that table being updated by the trigger belongs to a different database (which is probably not your case), you really need to review your design.

Comment: I want to reload only some data from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Search for this question and find below code to refresh data in EF :
`MyModelEntities.Refresh(System.Data.Objects.RefreshMode.StoreWins, TbMyRecord);`

Comment: What type the "TbMyRecord" is?

Answer (score 2):

There is an InsertOnSubmit event that fires as noted [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763516.aspx), not sure that's going to help you..

but there are various event fired when saving / modifying entities, but you'd have to bring your "trigger" logic into the code side, and then probably intelligently handle various Entity Changes.. here's more here : [How To Execute Business Logic When Saving Changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716714.aspx)

and after taking a deeper look at the title of your question it seems that you're trying to get the data from the updated table.. and as the comment suggests.. anything outside the scope of the entity "context" is going to have to be "reloaded". Now if that "loading" code is handled in your "change event" handling, you could accomplish this.. so why not just put all of that logic in your code layer? make the updates to your 2 "entities" and then save them in one swoop..

Comment: I want to reload only some data from database.

Comment: if you've got an entity that contains the data.. and if you know what the data "should" be, you can just set it.. if its some kind of aggregate, then you either need to load the entire entity, or perform the aggregation in code, and set the values..

Answer (score 1):

Though, not the answer you are after, I think you should move the "trigger" logic from the database to the application code. That will solve your problem, AND allow you to write a unit test verifying that data is updated correctly.